# Why do we need to declare NOT empty constructor in entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, constructor

I know that a constructor without parameter is necessary to be in Entity. But recently, I saw constructor with parameters too. I didn't understand, why it might be needed and how it works at all.

Comment: Not sure I'm getting your question. So, what's confusing you? May be you can show an example? If we are talking about a case when two constuctor exist - yes, it is possible. It is called overloading.

Comment: At least one nullary constructor is mandatory for entities to be instantiated by the framework via reflection. As long as you have one nullary constructor, it doesn't matter what other constructors may be available. Entities can have as many constructors, as long as there is one nullary. Where did you see this?

Comment: The reason why do you need constructor with parameters in another Class is the same for the entity. Primary fileds which are the main represetation of class data can be build with constructor, secondary filelds - with setters. By the way, java provides the empty constructor implicitly if you will not do so.

Comment: @J-Alex Yes, this is the answer on my question!

Comment: The fact is that you DO NOT need any other constructor than the default (no args) constructor. If you think you do then state clearly WHY you think that, and what exception you get if you don't have one. Having some identity fields is utterly irrelevant to what a JPA entity requires

Comment: Thank you, but I do not have any identity fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for hibernate entity you should provide at least one default constuctor without parameter. If you entity has many fields and just couple are of them are you can create constuctor/constructors with mandatory paremeters but default constructor(without params) should be in entity.

as you Entity it's a normal class you use it not only for hibernate mapping but for other components also.

also you can add static factory method to easy create class.

for exaple :

```
@Entity
class User{
//mandatory fields
private Long id;
private String userName;

//not mandatory fields:
private Date registrationDate;
private String nickName;

   public User(){//it's default constructor for hibernate entity creation 
   }

   public User( Long id ,String userName){ // you can create entity whenever when you want to create entity
....
   }
}
```

with User( Long id ,String userName) - you declare that if you need User instance
you should create it with mandatory field.

in case when you have User() constructor it's hard to understand what parameters are mandatory

Answer (score 1):

Internally to create instances of entity hibernate uses newInstance() method this method works only with default constructor only .thats if u provide any parameterised constructor along with that we have to provide default constructor also.