# Is it mandatory to use no args constructor using @entity annotation in java spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am working on a **spring boot** application (v2.1.5.RELEASE) with **h2** as an in-memory database. I created a simple project with a main and only one model **Person.java** with just 3 **private** fields. I have **no constructor** at all but when I launch the application and open the h2 console, I am still able to see the table created from the entity Person. I read from a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606432/why-do-we-need-to-declare-not-empty-constructor-in-entity) that a **no-args constructor** is needed when we use **@entity** annotation. Is it mandatory?

**Person.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String name;

    private double age;

    private String dateOfBirth;

}
```

**main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CommandLineApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(CommandLineApp.class);

    }
}
```

image-h2-console-showing-table
[image]

Comment: When you don't specify any constructor, a parameter-less constructor is implicitly added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need to declare NOT empty constructor in entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606432/why-do-we-need-to-declare-not-empty-constructor-in-entity)

Comment: @CodeSlave, In fact I saw from that particular question that a no-args constructor is mandatory for entity class but I was able to see a table created in my h2 console without any constructor in my entity class. I thought if there was some link between no-args constructor of entity and table creation by h2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of schema has nothing to do with the Java constructor. Spring and ORM vendors can read java fields using reflection, and also consider meta-information provided from annotations.

Constructor is just used to create java instances.

> I have no constructor at all but when I launch the application and
> open the h2 console, I am still able to see the table created from the
> entity Person

The table is created from all the info, that I have mentioned above. Nothing to do with constructors

As for your second question

> a no-args constructor is needed when we use @entity annotation. Is it
> mandatory?

This has to do with how an ORM vendor has made the framework and what requirements he has made for it to work. Specifically for **Hibernate yes it is mandatory**.

Retrieved from [Hibernate Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/quickstart/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic-entity)

> 2.2. The entity Java class
>
> - The no-argument constructor, which is also a JavaBean convention, is a requirement for all persistent classes. Hibernate needs to create
>   objects for you, using Java Reflection. The constructor can be
>   private. However, package or public visibility is required for runtime
>   proxy generation and efficient data retrieval without bytecode
>   instrumentation.

Answer (score 4):

Java implicitly adds a no-arg constructor to all classes when there is no constructors defined. If you define any parameterized constructor then the no-arg constructor will not be added.

According to the other SO question, it is mandatory to have no-arg constructor for initialization of the entities.

So the behavior is perfect here.

Comment: Have you checked from the DDL whether the table is auto-create if not exists?